# How to set a default value for enum type @GraphQLArgument

Tags: graphql-spqr

How to set a default value for enum type @GraphQLArgument?

```
public enum CursorDirection {
    @GraphQLEnumValue(name = "FORWARD")
    FORWARD,
    @GraphQLEnumValue(name = "BACKWARD")
    BACKWARD;
}
```

Setting to enum name as defaultValue gives below error..

```
@GraphQLArgument(name = "cursorDirection", description = CURSOR_DIRECTION_DESC, defaultValue = "FORWARD")
CursorDirection cursorDirection

Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'FORWARD': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
 at [Source: REDACTED (`StreamReadFeature.INCLUDE_SOURCE_IN_LOCATION` disabled); line: 1, column: 8]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:2481) ~[jackson-core-2.16.1.jar:2.16.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:762) ~[jackson-core-2.16.1.jar:2.16.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._reportInvalidToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:3042) ~[jackson-core-2.16.1.jar:2.16.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._handleOddValue(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:2085) ~[jackson-core-2.16.1.jar:2.16.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:812) ~[jackson-core-2.16.1.jar:2.16.1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Default values have to be valid JSON (I think when the expected type is `String` (and not enum) the value can be left unquoted, but not certain off the top of my head):

`defaultValue = "\"FORWARD\""`

Comment: Thanks @kaqqao for the quick response and setting defaultValue = "\"FORWARD\"" is working as expected.